# TypeError: resize() got multiple values for argument 'size'

Tags: python-3.x, image-segmentation

I'm trying to prepare my image data for image segmentation but I ran into an error. I read the PIL Image documentation and I think I sent all the parameters needed to the function. I put a * at the start of the line I'm getting the error.

```
from PIL.Image import Image
im = Image()
image_ids = next(os.walk(DATA_PATH))[1]

X = np.zeros((len(image_ids), IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS), dtype=np.uint8)
Y = np.zeros((len(image_ids), IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1), dtype=np.bool)

for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(image_ids), total=len(image_ids)):
    path = DATA_PATH
    img = imread(path + '/' + id_ + '/images/' + 'page' + id_ + '.png')[:,:IMG_CHANNELS]
*    img = im.resize(img, size = (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH))
    X[n] = img
    mask = np.zeros((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1), dtype=np.bool)
    for mask_file in next(os.walk(path + '/masks/'))[2]:
        mask_ = imread(path + '/masks/' + mask_file)
        mask_ = np.expand_dims(im.resize(mask_, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), mode='constant',
                                      preserve_range=True), axis=-1)
        mask = np.maximum(mask, mask_)
    Y[n] = mask

x_train=X

y_train=Y
```

I can't seem to find any solution to it. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: According to the documentation I found, the first argument for `resize` is supposed to be size.

Comment: img = im.resize((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH)) returns AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'resize' error

Comment: If you are wanting to resize `img`, you need `img = img.resize((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH))` and you don't need `im` for anything.